# How can i correctly pass a function to a eventListener?

Tags: javascript

I made a basic eventListener which creates an alert on button click. This one doesn't work (it calls the alert on the page load)

```html
function handleClick(){
   alert("hi!");
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",handleClick());
```

this one works instead, but i don't understand why

```html
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",function(){
    alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: `addEventListener("click",handleClick())` *brackets* adds the `return` of `handleClick`. Whereas `addEventListener("click",handleClick)` *no brackets* adds `handleClick` instead.

Answer (score -1):

with `handleClick()` you are executing the function when that statement is read. You need to pass in the function `handleClick` reference.

This:
`document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",handleClick);`